# Simplify a Cycle

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory

*Alternatively: That one challenge I forgot I had in the sandbox and is about stuff from Discrete Mathematics I learned like 5-6 months ago and kinda don't remember*

Given a path of vertices that form a cycle on a graph, output a simple version of the cycle. That is, if a vertex appears twice, snip out the part in between the two appearances.

### Context

Let \$u\$ and \$v\$ be vertices of graph \$G\$. If there is a cycle from \$u\$ to \$v\$ of length \$n\$, then there exists a simple cycle from \$u\$ to \$v\$ with length \$\le n\$.

This is because any cycle \$v_1, e_1, v_2, e_2, ..., e_m, v_m\$ with a vertex visited twice (that is, \$v_i = v_j\$ for some \$v_i\$ and \$v_j\$ in \$G\$, where \$ i < j\$), can be reduced to \$v_1, e_1, ..., e_i, v_j, e_{j+1}\$ and still be a valid cycle between \$u\$ and \$v\$.

For the sake of this challenge, the edges connecting vertices will be ignored, as the edge taken when going between vertices will be assumed arbitrary.

### Worked Example

Take the graph \$K_5\$:

[image]

One cycle between vertices \$1\$ and \$3\$ might look like:

[image]

That is, the path taken is `[1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 3, 5]`. However, that cycle can be simplified to:

[image]

Which has path `[1, 2, 3, 5]`. This cycle is a simple cycle, as only the first and last vertices are equal.

Note that cycles are snipped in the order they come.

### Rules

- There will always be a simpler cycle in the input.
- The input will be a list of vertices in a graph. Whether you take those as numbers, characters or some other way is up to you.
- There will always be at least 2 vertices.
- Each vertex has degree >= 2.
- Input and output can be given in any reasonable and convenient format.
- As the input represents a cycle, the vertex that is the start and end of the cycle will not be in the input.
- There won't be multiple overlapping simplified paths in the input.
- There'll be one and only one output for each input.

Note that the simple cycle may not be the shortest cycle, and the shortest cycle may not be the simple cycle.

### Test Cases

*Assuming that numbers are used as vertex labels*

```
[1,2,3,4,2,5] -> [1,2,5]
[4,3,6,2,3,8,5,2,8,7] -> [4,3,8,7]
[1,1,2] -> [1,2]
[1,2,7,2,7,2,3,7] -> [1,2,3,7]
```

This is code golf, so make sure you simplify the byte count of your answers.

Comment: Are the test cases unique? I might've misunderstood the problem, but wouldn't `[1, 2, 7]` be a valid answer as well for `[1,2,7,2,7,2,3,7]`, if you choose to snip the `7` first?

Comment: To expand on @CommandMaster 's comment, what's the expected output for `[1,2,1,3,4,5,6,2]`? It seems like the shortest cycle is `[1,2]`. But a simple left-to-right approach would return `[1,3,4,5,6,2]`.

Comment: @Arnauld [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2]. Remember that the simplest cycle may not be the shortest for this challenge

Comment: @CommandMaster it would be but it snips in order of how the input came

Comment: _it snips in order of how the input came_ -> I think that's what really clarifies the whole thing and should probably be mentioned in the challenge (I don't think it is).

Comment: @Arnauld I've added that extra clarification. Sorry for the confusion over that aspect of the challenge

Answer (score 11):

## Wolfram Mathematica, <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
#//.{a___,b_,___,b_,c___}:>{a,b,c}&
```

-1 byte thanks to @att.

Explanation:

- `#` and `&` define an anonymous function, e.g., `#+1&` is a function that adds 1 to its argument.
- `//.` is `ReplaceRepeated`, and keeps applying the pattern on the right to the expression on the left until its no longer changing
- `:>` is pattern replacement, it replaces the expression on the left with the expression on the right
- Finally, `_` means "any element" and `___` means any sequence of elements (including empty sequences). The variable before `_` or `___` assigns the matched expression to the variable.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: you don't need to name `c`

Comment: Indeed! It saves a character. That’s shows how new I am to this code gold thing.

Answer (score 8):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <del>43</del> 39 bytes

```
i:0(?v:l3p:l$4p
  /2~/
1+>3g:?!;:nao:4g
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiaTowKD92OmwzcDpsJDRwXG4gIC8yfi9cbjErPjNnOj8hOzpuYW86NGciLCJpbnB1dCI6IjEsIDIsIDcsIDIsIDcsIDIsIDMsIDciLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIn0=)

### Explanation

[image]

Top row copies every element. The raw data will be stored in the third row of the code box. (`:l2-3p`) The fourth row stores the last index each character is encountered. (`l2-$4p`).

The third row prints the data based on the value stored. First, get the number at the specified position. `3g`. Check if it's 0, if so exit. `?!;`. Print the number followed by a line break `nao`. Then we jump to the last occurrence of that character plus one `4g1+`

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
≬h€÷↔∩h
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4omsaOKCrMO34oaU4oipaCIsIiIsIlsxLDIsMyw0LDIsNV1cbls0LDMsNiwyLDMsOCw1LDIsOCw3XVxuWzEsMSwyXVxuWzEsMiw3LDIsNywyLDMsN10iXQ==)

```
≬       # three element lambda:
 h      #   head
  €     #   split by
   ÷    #   push each item to stack
```

This lambda takes a list. If length > 0 it splits by the first element and returns the last chunk. If length == 0 it does nothing.

```
    ↔   # apply the lambda and collect results until the the result doesn't change
     ∩  # transpose
      h # head
```

Comment: The `;` is unnecessary, as functions are full programs.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 11 bytes

```
(\w).*\1
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fI6ZcU08rxpBLxfD//2hDHSMdYx0TIGkayxVtAmSbgUUsdEyBtIWOOVDUUAeoCkwb6ZhDsTFQBgA) Link includes test cases. Takes input as a list of letters (or digits or `_`). If input as a string of non-newline characters is acceptable, then for 10 bytes:

```
(.).*\1
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fQ09TTyvGkEvF8P9/QyNjEyNTLhNjMyNjC1MjC3MuQ0MjLkMjcyA0NgcA) Link includes test cases.

Answer (score 4):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 6 bytes (12 nibbles)

```
.`.$/%$/$$@/
```

Approach based on [AndrovT's Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256928/95126): upvote that!

Vertices are represented by characters.

```
 `.             # iterate while unique
   $            # (starting with input):
     %$         #   split the result-so-far
       /$$      #   on its first element
    /     @     #   and get the last part
.               # now map over results of each iteration
           /    # returning the first element each time.
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 35 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>a&&a[0]+f(a.split(a[0]).pop())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbR1i5RTS0x2iBWO00jUa@4ICezRAPE1dQryC/Q0NT8n5yfV5yfk6qXk5@ukaahZGhkbGJkqqSpqQAC@voKQBFTJS40VSbGZkbGFqZGFuYglSBVJsZANroyQ0MjmElwwzAVGZkDobE5RCVEEZD3HwA) Link includes test cases. Takes input as a string of characters.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 67 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,b=[]:x and f(x[len(x)-x[::-1].index(x[0]):],b+x[:1])or b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/BboQgEEDvfsXEC5COm7JqNST2RywHrJglcZEoaejX29Hd7YGZ8HjDzITfeFt82YZ136duNvdhNJBw6HqtEhg/wsRTP1vPkyhSr1Qh9cX50SbC71oojcMbcanFssKwR7vFDTrI87yXeMUSK4q1huITTlDrrK8If5yPLdaUW2weQnWihhSJJP9XneCKzfOUL18@L9QtyyYa4GgPzp95u2xhdpGzL8@EysDhQoPdTeD2x8x4KC/j@IwJkUFYnY/c4YMgLe8EMpuC/Y52VAwXsf8B)

Reverse lookup approach. We find the last occurrence and jump to it

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 78 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,b=[]:x and f(x[1:],(b[:b.index(x[0])]if x[0]in b else b)+x[:1])or b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDdboQgEEbvfYqJN0I63ZRVqyGxL0K5kIopiYtESUOf3o7sbi/4O5xhvhB@4/fq6z5sxzEPy3gz0wgJzaC0TDD6CWaWlJAamVHSXJyfbCLyprl2M5wb58GAXXYLhr8kJYXm6wbmiHaPOwxQlqUSeMUaG5pbDa8fkEGrC9UQfs@XPba09tjdhSajjhSBJP9XZXDF7jHqpy8eB@pWFDMFONsDZcsxLntYXGTVp6@4LMDhSsFuY2D2Z1zwVJ7G@VjFeQFhcz4yh3eC9A@OY2VTsF/RTrLClR9/)

Takes a list of integers.

Idea is if we encounter an element we already passed through, we prune all elements between them

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.œR.Δε¬Qθ}P}€н
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f7@jkIL1zU85tPbQm8NyO2oDaR01rLuz9/z/aUMdIx1THDEga65jGAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/vaOTg/TOTTm39dCawHM7agNqHzWtubD3v87/6GhDHSMdUx0zIGmsYxqrA@Yb65iARIE8EyAbImcBVGUEJM3BaoCqoGrNodgYKBMLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
.œ         # Get all partitions of the (implicit) input-list
  R.Δ      # Find the last one (first one of the reversed list) that's truthy for:
     ε     #  Map over each part of the current partition:
      ¬    #   Get the head (without popping the list)
       Qθ  #   Check if it's equal to the last item in the list
     }P    #  After the map: check if all parts were truthy by taking the product
    }€     # After the findFirst, map over the parts of the found partition:
      н    #  Only leave their first integer
           # (after which this list is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 53 bytes

```hs
q(_,_:y)=f y
q(y,_)=f y
f(a:b)=a:q(break(==a)b)
f x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcZBCsIwEAXQfU7xFy4mMButFhqYk4iECTYYUquJLprTp6Bv9R76yfOy9F7Is3fNSkQzhRr7fyOpC1bUFQp11kwiaoM1EZts/alpheD@MsC7pvWLAyKuRz7xwGe@8PjbdOs7)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.filter(u=(x,i)=>a.lastIndexOf(u=+u||x)-i?0:u=a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLy0zpyS1SKPUVqNCJ1MTJJKTWFzimZeSWuGfBhTWLq2pqdDUzbQ3sCq1TdT8n5yfV5yfk6qXk5@ukaYRbahjpGOsYwIkTWM1NRVgQF9fASxlGsuFpsEEqNwMrMlCxxRIW@iYgzSCNJiABc0xtBjqAI1CNh3FDizKjXTModgYYjqyk4yx2YBpOlxL7H8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>17</s> 13 bytes

```
ＷΦθ¬λ«ι≔⊟⪪θιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDLTOnJLVIo1BHwS@/RCNHU1NToZqLM6AoM69EI1PTmovTsbg4Mz1PIyC/QCO4ICezBKQ0U1NTR6EQKFv7/7@JsZmRsYWpkYX5f92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＷΦθ¬λ«
```

Repeat until the input string is empty, but calculated as the input string excluding any characters with a non-zero index, so that the result of the calculation becomes the loop variable.

```
ι
```

Output the first character of the input string.

```
≔⊟⪪θιθ
```

Split the string on its first character and take the last part. Edit: Saved 4 bytes by copying this approach from @DominicvanEssen (who based it on another answer but I found his answer clearer).

Answer (score 2):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/index.html), 40 bytes

```
f(a:_++a:b?a:b)|notElem a b=a:f b
f[]=[]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m706ubSoqDK-IDE7uXjBgqWlJWm6Fjc10jQSreK1tROtkuyBWLMmL7_ENSc1VyFRIck20SpNIYkrLTrWNjoWon5XbmJmnoKtQppCtKGOkY45FBvrmEMVwAwGAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 121 bytes

Golfed version, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDBasMwDL33K0TZwWZpoGu3jkALY6dCx6Bjp9KDljiph@sEWx0rJd@eyU5XOnaRn/TekyX5HA129cenygleUFs4DQAKVcKeE4Gu8hk8OYfHzRs5bautzODdaoJ5VAJ8oQFSnp7RK8/VlfYkIgM9Hidwl8AkgWkE9zK5ZqeRevjVPLIgYgazv0ruE1r9K7J4dhUnwRglchCfy3BpWTuF@Q5OoG1z4BUW51ZhB6f8wYS1ShFZeeYa3pqMFX64DOUMbiKdwDoaOO@dw97Qcmy7cMBSmCzMuFla2sq54e9NsVIliVBN1b6hY8@dBCZazhe6FJjmtSU@vRdaSkwLVzdrXe2IGaNsRbsRA/S0tIX6fuVZ5WgslfEKMLvVbdd2Pw)

```scala
def f(l:List[Int])=l.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]){(a,i)=>if(a.contains(i))a.dropRight(a.length-a.lastIndexOf(i)-1)else a:+i}
```

Ungolfed version

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val testCases = List(
      List(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5),
      List(4, 3, 6, 2, 3, 8, 5, 2, 8, 7),
      List(1, 1, 2),
      List(1, 2, 7, 2, 7, 2, 3, 7)
    )

    testCases.foreach { input =>
      val result = f(input)
      println(s"Input: $input, Result: $result")
    }
  }

  def f(input: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    input.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]) { (acc, item) =>
      if (acc.contains(item)) {
        acc.dropRight(acc.length - acc.lastIndexOf(item) - 1)
      } else {
        acc :+ item
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes

#### Version 1

```javascript
f=(a,i=0,v=a[i])=>v?[v,...f(a,a.lastIndexOf(v)+1)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjUSfT1kCnzDYxOjNW09auzD66TEdPTy8NKJGol5NYXOKZl5Ja4Z@mUaapbagZaxUd@z85P684PydVLyc/XSNNI9pQx0jHWMcESJrGamoqwIC@vgJYyjSWC02DCVC5GViThY4pkLbQMQdpBGkwAQuaY2gx1AEahWw6ih1YlBvpmEOxMcR0ZCeBhP4DAA)

#### Version 2

```javascript
f=a=>a+a?[v=a[0],...f(a.slice(a.lastIndexOf(v)+1))]:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbR1i5RO9E@usw2MdogVkdPTy9NI1GvOCczORVI5yQWl3jmpaRW@KdplGlqG2pqxlol/k/OzyvOz0nVy8lP10jTiDbUMdIx1jEBkqaxmpoKMKCvrwCWMo3lQtNgAlRuBtZkoWMKpC10zEEaQRpMwILmGFoMdYBGIZuOYgcW5UY65lBsDDEd2Ukgof8A)